# Need to output two dimensional array as HTML Table using nested loops and Html.Raw (using Razor C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, razor

As the title suggests, I am trying to display a table in a webpage that lists the one to five times table, row by row.

Here is what I have so far.

```
@{ var oneToFiveTimesTable = new int[,] { 
        {1,  2,  3,  4,  5}, 
        {2,  4,  6,  8, 10}, 
        {3,  6,  9, 12, 15}, 
        {4,  8, 12, 16, 20}, 
        {5, 10, 15, 20, 25} 
    }; 
}
```

I know that I will need to use `@Html.Raw(string)` and have nested loops to control the rows and columns.

Comment: Show us the expected HTML output - it also might help you with your solution :)

Comment: Side note: please avoid long story of your life, "searched alot" and "thank you notes" in posts unless they directly related to your problem (like "how to write 'thank you' three times").

Comment: Please explain why "need to use @Html.Raw(string)" as it very unclear how it could be related to your question.

Comment: This is also part of the problem, I have been provided with just this part of the code and also need to do the HTML part too.

Comment: @rockdude1986 In that case, here's a start. http://jsfiddle.net/ecns325y/ Complete the rest of the table by hand, then start thinking about how you can write a loop to produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for(i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            <tr><td>@oneToFiveTimesTable[i][0].ToString()</td><td>@oneToFiveTimesTable[i][1].ToString()</td><td>@oneToFiveTimesTable[i][2].ToString()</td><td>@oneToFiveTimesTable[i][3].ToString()</td><td>@oneToFiveTimesTable[i][4].ToString()</td></tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```